# Google analytics API: different sum of sessions with 'ga:eventLabel' function and without it

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I added 'ga:eventLabel' function to my script and sum of sessions decreased from 2238 to 994. Why?

I expect the same result from both script

````
dim=['ga:eventLabel', 'ga:source','ga:sourceMedium']
met=['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']
start_date='2019-07-01'
end_date='2019-07-03'
transaction_type='Goal'
goal_number=''
refresh_token=token
condition=''
data_2=google_analytics_reporting_api_data_extraction(viewID,dim,met,start_date,end_date,refresh_token,transaction_type,goal_number,condition)

viewID='*********'
dim=['ga:source','ga:sourceMedium']
met=['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']
start_date='2019-07-01'
end_date='2019-07-03'
transaction_type='Goal'
goal_number=''
refresh_token=token
condition=''
data=google_analytics_reporting_api_data_extraction(viewID,dim,met,start_date,end_date, refresh_token,transaction_type, goal_number,condition)```
````

Here are the results: 
[image]

--

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries have two different meanings, and won't give you the same result, unless you have a data set, where all sessions have at least one event type hit associated with them.

**The first query says:** count all my users and sessions for the given date range, breaking it down by event label, source, source/medium and date. So in this case, you implicitly filter for any known event labels, where (not set) is an empty, but existing label for a recorded event. Sessions without any events are excluded.

**The second query says:** count all my users and sessions for the given date range, breaking it down by source, source/medium and date (regardless, if they had any events).

You can verify this behavior, if you create these custom reports in Google Analytics web UI. It is similar to querying custom dimensions: if no value was set for a given custom dimension, those records are excluded.

Comment: I noticed that at some days count sessions by first query (with EventLabel) more than by second (without EventLavel) query. Why can it be happening?

Comment: Two ideas at first. Have you checked, if your data is sampled? If a session contains multiple events with different labels, it gets counted for all label instances, so the sum might be greater.

Comment: 1) No sampled data. I added the samplingLevel = 'HIGHER_PRECISION' parameter. 2) What do you mean by "multiple event"?

Comment: Adding HIGHER_PRECISION might still result in sampled data. More important, if you use sessions as metric, a single session can show up for multiple event labels. Thus, summarizing them can result a higher number, than total number of sessions.

Comment: I got it, thx. But it's strange, how can a single session can show up for multiple event labels?

Comment: Event label is a hit-level dimension. So my single session can have multiple events and event labels associated with it. In your report, you are counting sessions by given breakdown, not distinctly distributing them among labels.

Comment: I apologize for so many questions, but how can I build df where I will count my sessions distinctly distributing them among labels?

Comment: 2) can a big number of 'max-results' metrics decide the 'sampled data' problem?

Comment: No problem, happy to help. 1) I'd consider this a business question first: if a session has multiple event labels, which label would contain this session? 2) Sampling is rather based on number of hits to be processed. See: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

Comment: Thx! I noticed strange thing: my number of sessions's column (ga:sessions) in Python script equals the number of unique events's column in https://analytics.google.com report ( I suppose that it's 'ga:users' function in API). 1) How can it happened?  Just because of this column in analytics.google using ga:sessions function and named incorrectly (Unique events)? 2) And do I think right: python's api just merge the functions (which I wrote in my Python scripts) to functions which written in  report's architecture (in https://analytics.google.com)?